# How to highlight the group row of an ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout, expandablelistview

With the following code based on [`State List Selector`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) I managed to highlight a single child row of an `ExpandableListView` when a user presses it on the display:

**XML State Selector code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item 
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/highlighted_entry" /> 

  <item 
      android:state_selected="true"
      android:drawable="@color/highlighted_entry" />

  <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

**XML ExpandableListView layout code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/exp_list_entry_selector" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/exp_list_entry_title"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="12dp"
       android:textColor="#000000" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code:**

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(    ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id ) 
{
    v.setSelected(true);    
    return false;
}
```

This same approach will not work if I try to highlight the Group Row (the entry of the `ListView` that is expandable): it will get highlighted when the user presses it (and expand or collapse it children), but after releasing it the background colour will return back to normal.

How can I highlight the group row regardless of whether it is expanded or not?

Comment: R u trying to highlight the expandlist on click, i mean do u need the user is knw which list has been clicked

Comment: @Rakshi - yeah, I need to highlight the entry of the list regardless if it is a child or parent row because user could need to do some action on it. Any ideas?

Comment: you try adding a image like an arrow pointing downwards so that the user can know that it is a expanded list..

Comment: do you have any idea about it ?

Answer (score 3):

By adding `android:background="@drawable/row_highlighter"` attribute to `child.xml` of `expandableListView`. and Creating a `row_highlighter.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

and source code:

```
int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                   .getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
parent.setItemChecked(index, true);
```

[Highlighting the selected item in the ExpandableListView](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-highlighting-selected-item-in.html)

Comment: thks for your answer, i'll check it out and get back to you, although it is a very outdated question ;D

Answer (score -1):

When you set the adapter, pass your own custom layout like this

```
SimpleCursorTreeAdapter mAdapter = new ListinoProdottiAdapter(null, ListinoProdottiActivity.this,

                                R.layout.my_simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                                R.layout.listino_prodotti_row,
                                ....
                        );
```

Inside  **R.layout.my_simple_expandable_list_item_1** (i set background to red)

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/red"
/>
```

Comment: Is there a solution using a `State List Selector`?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean with State List Selector ?

Comment: [Check here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)